# Pretty URL change variable seporator

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I am trying to pass variables by a pretty url which I can achive using the following:

`domain.com/exercises/lunge+with+dumbells`

And this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)$ index.php?exercise=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)/$ index.php?exercise=$1
```

Which is accessed in php using:

`$urlVars = $_GET["exercise"];`

However, I need my URLs to read like this:

`domain.com/exercises/lunge-with-dumbells`

I can get this to work using

`exercises/?exercise=lunge-with-dumbells` and this PHP function:

```
$urlVars = $_GET["exercise"];
$newString = str_replace("-", " ", $urlVars);
```

however, I would like a pretty URL with the variable string separated by `-` rather than `+`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To let your .htaccess match an url prettified with a "`-`" separator rather than a "`+`" separator you just need to change the regular expression that manages the rewrite rule to your php file:

Change the rules from:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)$ index.php?exercise=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)/$ index.php?exercise=$1
```

to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?exercise=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?exercise=$1
```

to split the regular expression in it's simplest components, we are going to create one that says

```
   ^ // match the beginning of a strings that start with
   ( 
   [ // a pattern consisting of
    a-z //a lowercase alphabet letter
    A-Z //a uppercase alphabet letter
    0-9 //a digit
    - //and the minus sign (here we changed from the + sign to the new value)
    ]
    + //one or more occurence of the combination described above
    )
```

for more details about regular expression and .htaccess please refer to : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html